# How to put figures into longtable

Tags: floats, longtable

Below is my code where I'm trying to put figures into `longtable`. I'm wondering how can I decrease the spaces between figures (columns) and how can I stretch the figures to both margins?

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}% for variety
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{20\baselineskip}

\renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}%
\begin{longtable}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises \label{fig: cc}}
\endhead
\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{example-image-duck} & 
\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{example-image-duck} & 
\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\\
%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use `@{}l@{}c@{}r@{}`  and `.33\textwidth`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest defining your own environment so as not to litter the document with instructions that should be local.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}% for variety

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\newenvironment{longfigure}[2][]{%
  % #1 (optional) is arbitrary code to be executed before the longtable
  % #2 is the column specification
  \renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}%
  \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}%
  #1%
  \begin{longtable}{#2}
}{\end{longtable}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{6pt}{20\baselineskip}

\begin{longfigure}[\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01\textwidth}]{@{}ccc@{}}
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises \label{fig:cc}}
\endfirsthead
  \caption*{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises (continued)}
\endhead
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} & 
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} & 
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\\
%
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
\end{longfigure}

\end{document}
```

The magic factor `0.01` for the `\tabcolsep` comes from the fact that we have three columns, each 32% of the `\textwidth`, so we need to divide the remaining space in four parts.

[image]

A modification for using `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}% for variety
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\newenvironment{longfigure}[2][]{%
  % #1 (optional) is arbitrary code to be executed before the longtable
  % #2 is the column specification
  \renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}%
  \expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{figure}%
  \setcounter{subfigure}{0}%
  \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}%
  #1%
  \begin{longtable}{#2}
}{\end{longtable}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{6pt}{20\baselineskip}

\begin{longfigure}[\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01\textwidth}]{@{}ccc@{}}
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises \label{fig:cc}}
\endfirsthead
  \caption*{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises (continued)}
\endhead
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\end{longfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since barbara beeton commented about the awkward spacing, here's a workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}% for variety
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\newenvironment{longfigure}[2][]{%
  % #1 (optional) is arbitrary code to be executed before the longtable
  % #2 is the column specification
  \renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}%
  \expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{figure}%
  \setcounter{subfigure}{0}%
  \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}%
  #1%
  \begin{longtable}{#2}
}{\end{longtable}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{6pt}{20\baselineskip}

\begin{longfigure}[{%
  \AtEndEnvironment{subfigure}{\vspace{4pt}}%
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{aboveskip=1pt}%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01\textwidth}%
}]{@{}ccc@{}}
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises \label{fig:cc}}
\endfirsthead
  \caption*{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises (continued)}
\endhead
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\
%
\end{longfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to additionally add subcaption for each figure?

Comment: @Math122 Yes, see addition.

Comment: Last question: you wrote: "The magic factor 0.01 for the \tabcolsep comes from the fact that we have three columns, each 32% of the \textwidth, so we need to divide the remaining space in four parts.". Why we are dividing by four? You mean number of columns + 1? What value should I use if I want to put 4 figures per row each with width `0.23\textwidth`?

Comment: @Math122 The `\tabcolsep` is inserted at the left and right of a column, but we removed two of these insertions with `@{}`. Three columns mean six `\tabcolsep`, minus two four remain.

Comment: Pedantic observation ... the (sub)captions appear attached more closely to the graphics below them, not the intended ones.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Added a workaround.

Comment: Thanks.  Significant improvement.

Comment: If you add `\label`s, you will need to add `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` in the first subfigure.  Otherwise \ref will return 2a instead of 1a.

Comment: Hi unfortunately if we put two longfigures then the first has number 1 but the second has number 3. How to fix that?

Comment: @Math122 You're right. Added `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` at the end of the definition of `longfigure`.

Comment: @egreg are you sure that `\addtocounter{figure}{-1} ` solves the problem? I tried different combinations of longfigures and standard figure environmnt (some with captions and some without) and the  numering is veery strange. And is it possible to leav the same number for each head of longtable? So that is the table is too long it spans two pages but the number of the table is the same in both captions (you skip the number for each subhead)

Answer (score 6):

By use of the `tabullarray` package:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{duckuments}% for variety
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begingroup
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My caption},
  label = {my-label}
                 ]{colspec={@{} XXX @{}}}

\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\\
%
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} \\
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Regarding OP comment, in `longtable` as well `longtblr`, which are not in `figure` float environment, to inserted images is not straightforward add subcaptions (as far as I know, `\captionof` macro for subfigure environments doesn't exist; I will be very glad if someone deny me) , so below is suggested dirty trick by which locally in group with `longtablr` is simulated sub-caption numbering by `\captionup{figure}{...}` command. The code should be self explanatory.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,varwidth}   % <===

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \captionsetup[figure]{aboveskip=-2ex, belowskip=1ex, name=}
    \renewcommand\thefigure{(\alph{figure})}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Mylong table width images},
  label = {my-label}
                 ]{colspec = {@{} XXX @{}},
                   measure = vbox,
                    rowsep = 0pt,
                   }        
% table body
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    \\
    \captionof{subfigure}{Sub figure A}\label{subfig:a}    &
    \captionof{figure}{Sub figure B}\label{subfig:b}    &
    \captionof{figure}{Sub figure C}\label{subfig:c}    \\ 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    &
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    \\
    \captionof{figure}{Sub figure D}\label{subfig:d}    &
    \captionof{figure}{Sub figure E}\label{subfig:e}    &
    \captionof{figure}{Sub figure F}\label{subfig:f}
\end{longtblr}
\setcounter{figure}{1} % so far set manually, for correct numbering of the next figure
\endgroup

\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Next figure}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

See sub-figures \ref{subfig:a}, \ref{subfig:f} in figure \ref{my-label} and figure \ref{fig:2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to additionally add subcaption for each figure?

Comment: @Math122, yes, it is possible, but not straightforward. Does this subcaption should be referable?

Comment: Yes it would be great but it's not very necessary

Comment: @Math122, if referencing is not an issue, than after row with image you only need to insert row with (sub)caption text. For referencing subcaption is in addendum suggested a trick which you may find useful. It will appear ASAP.

Answer (score 5):

The following code assures that the material in the `longtable` environment occupies the full width of the textblock.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltcaption}  % for \LTcaptype macro
\usepackage{duckuments} % for variety
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock

\begingroup % localize scope of the next few instructions
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lcr } % make table occupy full width

\caption{Empirical regularities during currency crises} 
\label{fig:cc}\\
\endhead

\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{example-image-duck} & 
\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{example-image-duck} & 
\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question, "Is it possible to additionally add [a] subcaption for each figure?" -- Short answer: "yes". Somewhat longer answer: You'll need to encase each graph in a `subfigure` environment and provide suitable `\caption` directives (and load the `subcaption` package). At this point, it probably makes little sense to continue using the machinery of the `longtable` package; instead, just embed the subfigures in an ordinary `figure` environment and separate them horizontally via `\hfill` directives.

The following screenshots display the first two rows of the first page and the final two rows of the second page of subfigures, respectively. Observe that the code loads the `alphalph` package and runs

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}
```

in order to switch to "extended alphabetical" numbering of the subfigures.

[image]

...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption} % <-- for 'subfigure' environment
\usepackage{alphalph} % extended alphabetical 'numbering'
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[p!]  % 1st full page of subfigures
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\caption{Empirical regularities during currency crises} 
\label{fig:cc}

\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill 
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill 
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure} 

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure} 

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck}
\end{subfigure} 

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure} 

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure} 

\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[p!] % 2nd full page of subfigures
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{Empirical regularities during currency crises, continued} 
\label{fig:cc}

\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \label{duck:a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill 
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill 
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure} 

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \label{duck:f}
\end{subfigure} 

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck}
\end{subfigure} 

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure} 

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} \end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth} 
\includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\caption{A duck} 
\end{subfigure} 

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to additionally add subcaption for each figure?

Comment: @Math122 - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: Thanks but with figure environment I can't split the figures into many pages as with longtable - I need to use `\ContinuedFloat` in that case. I tried to put the first figure like this:

`\begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} 
\caption{Dataset for Something  with an Arbitrary Caption to Highlight the Problem}
\end{subfigure} &` but I got an error "\setcaptionsubtype outside float"

Comment: @Math122 - On the apparent incompatibility between the `longtable` and `subfigure` environments: That was actually part of the reason I suggested to no longer employ the `longtable` framework. On the use of `\ContinuedFloat` in order to break up very long floats into chunks that fit on a page: This may actually be a blessing in disguise. If you have, say, 60 subfigures in total and 15 subfigures fit on a given page (i.e., five rows of three subfigures each), you probably want these figures to be placed on 4 pages all by themselves. Using a `longtable` will make that anything but easy.

Comment: @Math122 - Do also keep in mind that if your document has more than 26 subfigures, you won't be able to label them with lowercase roman-alphabetical characters. You'll need to run `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}` if you're ok with (arabic) numerical labels, i.e., `(1)`, `(2)`, etc for the subfigures. Alternatively, you could run `\usepackage{alphalph} \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}` to generate "alphabetical" labels of the form `(a)`, `(b)`, ... `(z)`, `(aa)`, `(ab)`, ... `(az)`, `(ba)`, etc.

Comment: Good to know, thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

The following code based on `xltabular` instead of `longtable` may serve as a starting point. The horizontal space between the images can ba adjusted by changing the value of `\tabcolsep` to your liking.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{ltcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}% for variety
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{20\baselineskip}

\renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}%
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises \label{fig: cc}}
\endhead
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} & 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} & 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}\\
%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} \\
\end{xltabular}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to additionally add subcaption for each figure?